# oracle hint over several joins with different methods

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, optimizer-hints

I'm trying to force the oracle database 11g express edition to make the JOINs with two specific methods in a two JOINs SELECT, but it's not working when I try to do it with the USE_MERGE and the USE_NL hints. My SELECT looks like this:

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED USE_MERGE(sp) USE_NL(p) FULL(s) FULL(sp) FULL(p) */ DISTINCT s.*
FROM s, sp, p
WHERE s.sn = sp.sn AND
              p.pn = sp.pn AND
              color = 'Rojo';
```

but the actual explain plan that I'm getting is this one:

[explain plan that I'm getting from oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C063A.png)

I'm really desperate with this and I've been looking at the great oracle documentation but I'm still unable to achieve it. There's this example that looks quite similar but I don't know why's not working with the combination that I'm trying. The next code is the example provided from Oracle:

```
SELECT /*+ LEADING(e2 e1) USE_NL(e1) INDEX(e1 emp_emp_id_pk) 
           USE_MERGE(j) FULL(j) */
    e1.first_name, e1.last_name, j.job_id, sum(e2.salary) total_sal
  FROM employees e1, employees e2, job_history j
  WHERE e1.employee_id = e2.manager_id
    AND e1.employee_id = j.employee_id
    AND e1.hire_date = j.start_date
  GROUP BY e1.first_name, e1.last_name, j.job_id
  ORDER BY total_sal;
```

Thanks in advance for your help :D

Comment: For start you should change your conditions to the proper INNER JOIN syntax since oracle recommend it: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm

Comment: by the way, that implicit joins (having two tables in the from clause) is a deprecated syntax, and it's recommended to switch to the modern, explicit, syntax: Learn how to use explicit join syntax. Aaron Bertrand did some [**writting**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it

Comment: Yes, I know it should not be written that way but I'm forced to it in the requirements, thanks for the advice anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `USE_MERGE(s sp)` instead of `USE_MERGE(sp)`.  But I can't explain *why* that works.  Hints are tricky, it's best to avoid them as much as possible.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8387b/3) demonstrating the new hint working.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now and I'm being able to compare the differences between the different joins.